# Redirect every page to another domain besides index page with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect every page to another domain besides index page. In my case index.html, every other page mydomain/page2.html, mydomain.com/subfolder/subdolder/page.html etc to www.google.com.

Right now I have something like this, but then everything will get redirected. I would like to leave only leave index.html on root untouched.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http:/www.google.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !(^|/)index\.html http:/www.google.com [R=301,L,NC]
```